# CIFAR10 dataset has no attribute load_data()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I am using tensorflow version 2.0.1. In my Jupyter notebook I use:

```
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()
```

however, it does not work and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.datasets.cifar10' has no attribute 'load_data'
```

Also, in autocomplete I see load_data() for CIFAR100, but nothing shown for CIFAR10.

Comment: I am a bit confused: you are reporting CIFAR10 usage error, trying to call `tf.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()` and got error on `keras.datasets.cifar10`. May you please recheck your description?

Comment: Excuse me if there is ambiguity. I mean other datasets like CIFAR100 have load_data method, but CIFAR10 has not. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with `tf.version==2.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

I am able to load `cifar10` dataset using `load_data` method as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

Output:

```
2.0.1
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
170500096/170498071 [==============================] - 5s 0us/step
```

For more information you can refer [Loads CIFAR10 dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/cifar10.py).